# Is it possible for App Store not to convert USD to local currency?

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

i have an app that has IAP. its 0.99 $. but app store converts usd to local currency.
i dont want it to e converted. i checked the itunesconnect. but i didnt find anything for fixing price to USD. is it possible to fix currency to just USD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that, for a good number of reasons :

- First of all, consumers should not have to know the change rate from their local, everyday currency to the dollar. Pricing information should not be confusing therefore should be in the natural currency of the user
- Furthermore, AppStore goods consumer prices aren't the same across countries. This isn't just to make them look good (ie. .99$ ~ .79€ rather than .7761€ on current rate), Apple accounts for the variation of VAT and local, country-specific taxes so that the all-tax-included final cut for developers is roughly the same across countries. So for instance a French customer will pay more for the same good than a US customer because Apple has to give 15% of that income.

So for instance .99$ = .7761€ and .7761€ + 15% = .8925€ ~ .89€ (which is the actual french appstore price for something sold .99$ in the US) = 1.13$

Hence something sold .99$ is really sold 1.13$ to your customer

Bottom line : if you are worried about your final cut, don't be. You will roughly get 70% of your US price, no matter the country you sale it in.

Comment: what does apple check for currency? does it check General Settings or iTunes account country?

Comment: Accounts are country specific, and the country is determined at the moment of creation. To my knowledge, you cannot migrate one account onto another country.